# Azure IoT Hub sql query

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I am trying to query the IoT hub devices twins using query language. I have the following code snippet which is not working.I am not getting any results. When i replace dt with some hard coded date then i will get the device list. Is it like I cant pass a variable using this queries to hub? please help me.

```
   var dt = new Date();
         dt.setDate( dt.getDate() - 4 );
         console.log(dt);


var query = registry.createQuery('SELECT * FROM devices where lastActivityTime > dt', 100);
var onResults = function(err, results) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch the results: ' + err.message);
  } else {
    // Do something with the results
    results.forEach(function(twin) {
      console.log(twin.deviceId);
    });

    if (query.hasMoreResults) {
        query.nextAsTwin(onResults);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: In your code, you are not using the value of dt in your query, you are literally using the characters 'dt'.  `SELECT * FROM devices where lastActivityTime > ${dt}` is something you can try. This should put the value in your query.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It tried ${dt} and $dt as well getting "Failed to fetch the results: Error:". I didnt find any document or example code to pass variables to query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using a JavaScript template string - note the use of **`** and **'** in the example:

```
var dt = new Date();
dt.setDate( dt.getDate() - 3);
var dateString = dt.toISOString();

var query = registry.createQuery(`SELECT * FROM devices WHERE lastActivityTime > '${dateString}'`, 100);
```

Comment: thanks for the response. When you hard code the date and pass to the query works. but  when i generate using code  doesn't work. could'nt figure out                                                                                             
 var dt = new Date(new Date().toUTCString());
         dt.setDate( dt.getDate() - 3);

Comment: The string format I used in the snippet above worked in my environment. You need to check exactly what date format you're using. The query language expects the the date to be represented as a string - I believe in ISO date format. I'll update the snippet above to illustrate.

Comment: the following worked for me.var registry = Registry.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
var today =  moment.utc().subtract(7, 'days'); 
var query = registry.createQuery(`SELECT * FROM devices where lastActivityTime < '${today}'`, 1);